# Datastructure to find/search and add?

Tags: java, list, data-structures, treeset

I need to add the strings in Data structure(DS). Later I need to find the string and then remove it based on same condition.

Hashset can be best fit here as it provides O(1) complexity  for search and removal of given element also will just require updating  parent
right or left node. In Arraylist/Array it will be O(n) for search and same for removal.

Per my understanding Hashset will be better here as i need to search a large number of elements and if found remove it.

My question :- Is Hashset or some other DS better here ?

Comment: What is your problem/question?

Comment: added my question .

Answer (score 1):

Usually such tasks are best handled by [Trie data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) and the variations of it.
Alternatively you can use a hash table, however it doesn't guarantee worst-case complexity.

Comment: why hashtable, i dont have requirement for key-value pair ? Also what's the downside of Treeset ? How Trie is better then treeset in this case ?

Comment: Hash table can be used for both hash map and hash set, you are confusing.

Comment: Yeah you are right we should use hashset not treeset. Somehow i forgot hashset implementation. Updated mine post

Comment: But sure Trie will not be fit here as I don't have to search with prefix

Answer (score 0):

As usual, it depends on your needs:

- if you just need to add String instances, retrieve and delete them, this is no brainer - `HashSet` is your choice (`TreeSet` has worse asymptotic complexity and it is suitable in case that you need *order* of String instances for some reason, e.g. alphabetically)
- if you wish to store and efficiently search all String instances *with the specified prefix*, use Trie as correctly mentioned in Serge Rogatch's answer
- if you wish to check if pattern exists in the specified String instance or not, use [Suffix tree](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pattern-searching-set-8-suffix-tree-introduction/)